# Тип EditText для заметок

Tags: java, android, android-studio

У меня есть EditText, в который пишется заметка, какой тип надо выбрать, чтобы была не галка в нижнем правом углу клавиатуры, а enter (переход на следующую строку)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить `android:inputType="text|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"`